# use validate method to post the data that is assigned to particular user in django rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have user registration with user and project as foreign key and using serializer I wanted to choose only that project that is assigned to particular user but I can't figure out how to use validate method

So user can choose only that project which is assigned to him in registration process

Comment: can you please provide more info on your models which shows relationship of user and project.

Comment: ```    user = models.ForeignKey(
        'users.User',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='project_user_registration_set',
        verbose_name='gebruiker',
    )
    project = models.ForeignKey(
        'Project',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='project_user_registration_set',
        verbose_name='project',
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can validate and field with `validate_fieldname`, you can for example do (depending on how the user/project mapping is set up)

```
class ProjectUserRegistrationSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    ...

    def validate_project(self, value):
        user_id = self.context['request'].user.pk
        if not value.users.filter(pk=user_id).exists():
            raise serializers.ValidationError("You are not welcome in this project.")
```

And some totally unrelated comments

You probably want the `id` field (and possibly some others) to be read-only which you do by adding `read_only_fields = ('id',)` to your `Meta` class.

```
context = super(ProjectUserRegistrationViewSet, self).get_serializer_context()
```

can be simplified to just

```
context = super().get_serializer_context()
```

If you are not planning to support python2.

Comment: its not working giving me error ```Field 'id' expected a number but got <Project: 012345>.```

Comment: I just updated  my answer to fix that, sorry!

Comment: ```AttributeError at /projects/project-registration/
'Project' object has no attribute 'users'```

Comment: i just took a guess on how your users and projects are mapped as you didnt provide this, try fill in the code that works for you and how you modelled it.

Comment: Edit your question and add the Project model too.

Comment: same I am also using user and project in that model

Comment: I take it Project and User has some relation, in addition to ProjectUserRegistration, that you want to check and validate, right? so use that reverse relation name instead of `users`.

Comment: Whats not obvious is what you mean with "choose only that project that is assigned to particular user"

Comment: I added the field of model in question now can you check please?

Comment: No, add your Project model too, and please add all of the model, including the "class" row.

Comment: yeah for example I added two projects and assigned one project to user and when logged in user post their user registeration from there he can  choose the projects which he is assigned if he choose other he get validation error

Comment: So what does "assigned one project" mean? is there something in Project that points to the users assigned to it that we havent seen in your question? Just add your Project model to the question and we can figure it out!

Answer (score 0):

Guessing what the project model looks like.

```
class ProjectUserRegistrationSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ProjectUserRegistration
        fields = (
            'id',
            'date',
            'start',
            'start_note',
            'started',
            'started_at_location',
            'end',
            'end_note',
            'ended',
            'ended_at_location',
            'project',
        )

    def validate(self, attrs):
        # validated the data first 
        validated_data = super().validate(attrs)
        # Grab user and project from validated data
        user = validated_data.get("user")
        project = validated_data.get("project")
        if Project.objects.filter(id=project.id, users__in=[user]).exists() == False:
            raise ValidationError("user not added to project")
        return validated_data
```